# Monodroid - Intent Filter for Google Maps

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm trying to respond to Google Maps Uri intent for my Activity. After a quick Google search, I found this:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="maps.google.com" />
    <data android:scheme="geo" />
</intent-filter>
```

source: [How intercept a google maps intent in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5472940/how-intercept-a-google-maps-intent-in-android)
What's the equivalent of this Intent Filter in Xamarin.Android for my Activity?

Currently, I attempted this:

```
[IntentFilter(new[] { "android.intent.action.VIEW" }, Categories = new[] {"android.intent.category.DEFAULT", "android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"}, DataScheme = "https", DataHost = "maps.google.com" )]
```

But it doesn't seem to work. I'm quite confused on how to specify the additional

```
<data android:scheme="geo" />
```

Any pointers? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there's different way to write them. For example, the following

```
[IntentFilter (new[]{Intent.ActionView}]
```

produces `<action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />`

And for category: [**Link**](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/?link=P%3aAndroid.App.IntentFilterAttribute.Categories) and [**Examples**](http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/working_with_androidmanifest.xml/)