# Android 6.0 intent filter not working for Google Maps

Tags: android, google-maps, android-6.0-marshmallow, intentfilter

As I know

> Android App Links on Android 6.0 (API level 23) and higher allow an
>   app to designate itself as the default handler of a given type of
>   link. If the user doesn't want the app to be the default handler, they
>   can override this behavior from their device's system settings.

But the problem is I am not using any other website but
I only want to open Link of map location like
https://maps.google.com/?q=x.xx,y.yy

And I wrote

```
     <intent-filter
                android:autoVerify="true">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:host="maps.google.com"
                    android:scheme="https" />

            </intent-filter>
```

But It's not working always it opens Maps applications then what I have to do?

Please guide me as thanks in advance!.

Remember It's working on lower than 6.0

Comment: You might want to describe how you are doing testing. Also have you seen this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30305404/295004

Comment: It's not intercepting always opening google map

Comment: Actually it's working on lolipop but not on higher versions